# Sql Server - Replace only the first characters in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I replace only the the first zeros in a string?
Example:

```
string : '0000089001232100'
result:  '89001232100'
```

I can't use SQL Server `REPLACE` function since I don't want all my zeros to be replaced.
Thanks

Comment: What about just converting the string to `int` or `bigint`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select substring(ColumnName, patindex('%[^0]%',ColumnName), 10)` should give you what you need.

Also look into the `RIGHT` and `LEFT` functions. They strip a string from the left or right side, respectively.

If you wanted to use `RIGHT`, you could get the index of the first 'wanted' character using `CHARINDEX`(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx), then use that index as the point to strip from in your `RIGHT` function.

Answer (score 2):

If the string always have only numbers, you could use this:

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(30)
SET @String = '0000089001232100'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CONVERT(NUMERIC(20,0),@String))
```